# Convert pinyin to Chinese Character

Tags: translate

I want to take pinyin (english) as an input and return Chinese characters that user can choose from. I saw that this has been implemented in many place (support by OS keyboards and various websites), but can't find a library to do it.

Or possibly even doing it myself if it's not that complex or require large amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is use [javachinesepinyin](https://code.google.com/p/javachinesepinyin/), a lightweight Chinese Pinyin Input Method.
You can find related code [here](https://code.google.com/p/javachinesepinyin/source/browse/trunk/javachinesepinyin/src/main/java/pinyin/PinyinTest.java).

```java
private String[] pinyinToWord(String[] o) {
    Result ret = null;
    try {
        ret = ptw.labelStateOfNodes(Arrays.asList(o));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    Map<Double, String> results = new HashMap<Double, String>();
    if (null != ret && ret.states() != null) {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < ret.states()[o.length - 1].length; pos++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int[] statePath = Viterbi.getStatePath(ret.states(), ret.psai(), o.length - 1, o.length, pos);
            for (int state : statePath) {
                Character name = ptw.getStateBy(state);
                sb.append(name).append(" ");
            }
            results.put(ret.delta()[o.length - 1][pos], sb.toString());
        }
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>(results.keySet());
        Collections.sort(list);
        Collections.reverse(list);
        return results.get(list.get(0)).trim().split(" ");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Intro Slides in English: http://docs.google.com/present/edit?id=0AbbbdNFzwcADZGR3Z3N0NG1fMTk4M2hraGZjNmRw&hl=en

Live Demo: http://951438.appspot.com/pinyin.jsp?txt=zhongwenpinyinshurufa

If advanced features are needed, maybe you should consider use [Rime Input Method Engine](https://code.google.com/p/rimeime/) or [sunpinyin](https://github.com/sunpinyin/sunpinyin).

FYI, [Python Binding for sunpinyin](https://code.google.com/p/sunpinyin/wiki/PythonBinding).